# How to hide previous div from current target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class='selected><div class="test"></div><div class="cancel"></div></div>
```

I need to hide the div with class selected after the cancel class is clicked. There are many of these, therefore it has to be the previous one.

I tried doing this but it does not work:

```
 $(document).on('click','.cancel',(e)=>{


        $(e.currentTarget).prev('.selected').hide()
    })
```

It registers the click but does not hide `.selected`

Comment: `.selected` is the parent, not the previous sibling. `.test` is the previous sibling of `.cancel`

Comment: `$(e.currentTarget).closest('div.selected').hide()`

Comment: @joey.e Do you want to also want hide the cancel button?

Answer (score 1):

Please put the ending class quotation mark `<div class='selected>` to `<div class='selected'>` and use the following code because `.selected` is parent so:

```
$(".cancel").on("click",function(e){
 $(this).closest('.selected').hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `closest` to get the closest ancestor.  Or to get the sibling using `prev`, update your HTML.

Both will solve your issue, but not sure from question if you want to hide the cancel, or not.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cancel', (e) => {
  $(e.currentTarget).prev('.selected').hide()
})

$(document).on('click', '.cancel', (e) => {
  $(e.currentTarget).closest('.selected').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='selected'>
  <div class="test">Selected Parent</div>
  <div class="cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
  <div class='selected'>
    <div class="test">Selected Sibling</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

This approach will find the sibling, but hide the parent.  Seems like what you really want.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cancel', (e) => {
  $(e.currentTarget).prev('.selected').parent().hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="test selected">Selected Parent</div>
  <div class="cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably they see the first code which is wrong with the original code.

Comment: Take a look at my second snippet.  That seems to solve the issue too.

Comment: We have the exact html that the OP is using. There's no need to present an alternative structure, that's just going to add confusion. Keep it simple.

Comment: @KevinB 1.  These are working snippets.  2. Each HTML is a different structure to solve OP's issue.  And there is a need to present an alternative structure if it solves OP's problem.  `It registers the click but does not hide .selected`  That is due to the structure.

Comment: `.selected` is parent of `.cancel`. he's just missing the quotation in markup.

Comment: @Azhar Are you sure OP does not also want to hide the cancel button?  I added comment to original question...  He is also using prev and that will not return the parent.

Comment: Actually the `.cancel` div inside the `.selected` and he's trying to hide the `.selected` div.